# Problem with cross casting in Visual Studio 2003

Tags: c++, exception, visual-studio-2003

I am using `Visual Studio 2003` to compile and run following program.

There are 4 assignment operation where I expect 2 of them to run ok and 2 of them to raise exception. There is a dynamic casting inside overloaded `= operator` which expect to fail during non proper cross casting (Casting from `Apple` to `Orange` or `Orange` to `Apple`). But in my case all the 4 operations are failing ( Raising exception ). I have run the same code in `Visual Studio 2008` and it is working fine as expected. But moving entire project to `Visual Studio 2008` is difficult. Is this a problem of `Visual Studio 2003`? If so, is there any way to fix this?

Note: class `Fruit` is read only and cannot be changed.

```
class Fruit
{
public:
    virtual void operator = ( const Fruit& fruit )
    {
    }
};

class Apple : public Fruit
{
public:
    virtual void operator = ( const Fruit& fruit )
    {
        Apple& apple = dynamic_cast<Apple&>( fruit );
    }
};

class Mango : public Fruit
{
public:
    virtual void operator = ( const Fruit& fruit )
    {
        Mango& mango = dynamic_cast<Mango&>( fruit );
    }
};

int main( void )
{
    Apple apple;
    Mango mango;
    Fruit* fruit[] = { &apple, &mango };

    *fruit[0] = *fruit[0]; /* Expect to work ok */
    *fruit[0] = *fruit[1]; /* Expect an exception */
    *fruit[1] = *fruit[0]; /* Expect an exception */
    *fruit[1] = *fruit[1]; /* Expect to work ok */
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you enabled RTTI in your VS 2003 project settings?

Comment: Besides your question, you should always declare the parameter of assignment operator to const&. Even if it works without const, a user would not _expect_ a side effect on the right hand of the assigment it writes (e.g. your *fruit[0] = *fruit[1] _could_ alter the object at *fruit[1] in any way):

virtual void operator = ( const Fruit& fruit ) {..}

Only cases where non-const makes sense are usually some kind of "move" semantics..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check `Enable Run-time type information (RTTI)` in Project Settings. 
Category "C++ Language".

In VC6 at least it will not be enabled by default.

Comment: If the parent class was compiled to a library without RTTI turned on, and you can't recompile it, you may be out of luck.